# Does using the guest account in Ubuntu help for Spectre and Meltdown protection?

Tags: ubuntu, intel, patch

I was wondering if I use my computer running Ubuntu only for browsing while using the guest account on an unpatched PC logging in to any site I browse - will it be possible to steal any passwords typed into the browser or not?

Can e.g. a harmful web site steal my administrator password for the PC or even the WiFi password?

Answer (score 3):

[Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)) and [Meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability)) are 2 different security issues that both work using a side channel attack *that is not remotely exploitable all by itself* so if you use your own computer (or someone elses) with only one user logged on, there is no way anyone can read anything even if it's unpatched.¹

On a patched computer running Ubuntu (just run `apt dist-upgrade`), the Intel Microcode and Linux KPTI will fully protect you even when 2 users would be logged onto the computer and the other user will not be able to read your passwords even if you use them, contrarily to Windows which needs a firmware (BIOS/UEFI/...) update to mitigate against Spectre only as Meltdown has been taken care of by Microsoft and Spectre needs Intel µcode.

¹ <sup>Yes, for all the security gurus out there, there is a possibility that *another* exploit would take control and that one would *theoretically* be able to read memory on an unpatched computer but let's not confuse the OP as no known exploits exist in the wild at the time of this writing.</sup>

Comment: P.S. So basically all Cloud providers should worry about this, you on your computer on Ubuntu should not worry.  **Keep your system updated though as *today* there are no *known* exploits, but that *will change in the future!***

Comment: There is rowhammer.js is there not Spectre.js yet?  ...  there is qubesOS but using a modern kernel (4.14+) is probably enough.

Comment: Mitigation of these bugs isn't just "patching", parts of it are only able to be resolved by a redesign of hardware architecture.  Guest account doesn't protect as Fabby has indicated.